# How to accept backbone route which starts with #someNumber

Tags: backbone.js

I wanted to allow any routes which start with # and any number

Example :

```
http://127.0.0.1/mypage/#435fsdfd
```

This should basically execute renderMyPage.

Tried below things but didn't work

```
routes : { 

    "" : "renderMyPage",
    "#:/" : "renderMyPage"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

If your application is not being served from the root url / of your domain, you need to tell History where the root really is

```
Backbone.history.start({root: "/mypage/"});
```

you don't need to define the hash in the routes, if you just want to match 'something' on the hash this is enough:

```
routes : { 
  "" : "renderMyPage",
  ":value" : "renderMyPage"
},

renderMyPage: function (value) {

}
```

in the latest backbone (0.9.10) you can use optional arguments so you can do everything in one route

```
routes : { 
  "(:value)" : "renderMyPage"
},
```